# Can APK be installed in a different "buildTypes" mode for an application available on the Play Console?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-console

there are "debug" and "release" structures in our application as **buildTypes**. We always uploaded our apps to the Play Console in "release" mode.

Now we want to create a "sandbox" mode and we want to upload the apk in "release" mode and sometimes in "sandbox" mode to the play store and publish it in production environment.

Will this create a problem on the Play Console? Subsequent app updates, in-app purchases, etc. Could it pose a problem in a different way?